# Changing packet payload with tc

Tags: networking, filter, tc, traffic-shaping

How can tc be used to match a particular payload of an ingress packet, e.g., if the first 32 bits of payload of an IP/UDP packet are equal to some constant `$c`, the value `$c` should be changed to `$d`? This should work in particular for variable length IP headers.

It appears that the `u32` filter should be able to perform the matching. Is the following attempt correct? I am not sure about the `nexthdr` part in particular.

```
tc filter add dev protocol ip parent ffff: u32 match $c 0xffffffff at nexthdr+8
```

Now `pedit` can be used to change the packet but I don't see a way to write `$d` in the UDP payload of a packet with variable length IP header.

Any help is appreciated.